# How to get photo ID in ReactJS App from JSONPlaceholder for Modal Window to see details of photo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with ReactJS Photobrowser App which is I can't get photo ID for Modal Window to see clicked photo from the thumbnail list of the photos.

Here is the PhotoLoader.js React Component source code below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal.js';
import Axios from 'axios';
import './PhotoLoader.css';
import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

class PhotoLoader extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            photosPaginated: [], // will hold the results from our ajax call
            show: false
        }
        this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
        this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);
        this.loadPhotosPaginated();
    }   

    loadPhotosPaginated = () => {
       Axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_start=0&_limit=40')
            .then(response => {
            const photosPaginated = response.data;
            this.setState({ photosPaginated });
       });
    };

    showModal = () => {
        this.setState({ show: true });
    };

    hideModal = () => {
        this.setState({ show: false });
    };

    render() {
  
        return (
            <Container className="PhotoLoader-photobrowser-grid-container">
                <Modal show={this.state.show} handleClose={this.hideModal}></Modal>
                { this.state.photosPaginated.map(photo => <Button key={photo.id+"_button"} className="PhotoLoader-photo-button" onClick={this.showModal}><Image key={photo.id+"_photo"} src={photo.thumbnailUrl} className="PhotoLoader-thumbnail" thumbnail></Image></Button>)}
           </Container>
       );
  
    };

}

export default PhotoLoader;
```

And here is Modal.js source code file below.

```
import React from 'react';
import './modal.css';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Axios from 'axios';
import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image';

var title;
var url;

const loadPhoto = (id) => {

    Axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/'+id)
      .then(response => {
        title = response.data.title;
        url = response.data.url;
    });
    
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{title}</p>
        <Image src={url} className="PhotoLoader-large" fluid />
      </div>
    );
};

const Modal = ({ handleClose, show, children }) => {

const showHideClassName = show ? "modal display-block" : "modal display-none";

    return (
        <div className={showHideClassName}>
            <section className="modal-main">
                {children}
                {loadPhoto(1)} //on this function I need to get correct ID from clicked photo on PhotoLoader.js React Component and not just number 1
                <div className="clear"></div>
                    <Button onClick={handleClose}>
                        Close
                    </Button>
           </section>
       </div>
    );
};

export default Modal;
```

Okay what is my problem is?

On Modal.js has a line {loadPhoto(1)} where number 1 is just ID for needed photo that be must to get dynamically from PhotoLoader.js file some how. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be handled by passing the id to show model method as follows

```
showModal = (id) => {
    this.setState({ show: true, id: id });
  };
```

and in the model page you can use this value.

[Code Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-platform-2v9m9?file=/src/App.js:816-885)

Comment: This answer helped me a forward but is is not work 100 %. On first click Modal shows empty photo and second click photo which I am clicked first and so on.

Comment: Now I accepted your answer. It helped me to do things to get it near to work 100 %.